# Comparison of the functions print between Python and R

Tags: python, r, performance

Python is usually much faster than R but the following code takes more time in Python than in R.

```
# R
for (i in 1:10000){print(i)}
# It takes less than a second

###############################################

# Python
for i in xrange(10000):
    print i
# It takes 5 minutes!
```

What explain this difference?

Note: The point of my question is not to know how to increase the performance of my code but "why is Python much slower than R at running this code".

Comment: `range(10000)` builds a 10000 element list, rather than just iterate through the numbers. Use `xrange(10000)` instead.

Comment: Even with the overhead of `range`, that code still runs in a fraction of a second for me. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I assume there's a big picture issue you're actually trying to get at. It might be nice to see that problem rather than this trivial one...especially since in R you could just type `print(1:10000)`.

Comment: Indeed the point I wanted to make is not about what is the most efficient way to print on the screen all these numbers but why is Python slower than R for this code. Still I changed `range` to `xrange` as it does not change much of the story

Comment: If it takes 5 minutes to run that python code, there's something wrong with your system...

Comment: I think printing to stdout isn't the best way to do comparisons. Return with a tr00 algorithm and we'll talk.

Comment: On my system the Python takes 0.1 seconds. I suspect the problem is your *terminal* is slow for some reason. To confirm this, try `python -c "for i in xrange(10000): print i" > output.txt`. If that's fast, then it's not `print` that's slow, it's writing to a terminal.

Comment: @SteveJessop Oh ok, the problem comes from my computer. Yes the codeline you gave me is fast. Note: I am running Python on IDLE, not on the terminal.

Comment: @Remi.b: you can further confirm whether it's IDLE's terminal output that's slow, or something else about IDLE, by running `with open('output.txt', 'w') as out: for i in xrange(10000): print >>out, i` under IDLE. If that's fast too, then it's specifically IDLE's terminal output slowing things down.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes that's fast as well! Could I do something to increase the "IDLE's terminal output"? Should I redownload?

Comment: @Remi.b what are your system specs? Ram, OS????

Comment: @KDawG OSX 10.8.5, Memory: 4GO, Python and IDLE version: 2.7.5

Comment: @Volatility just a side note, but `1:10000` in `R` also builds the full 10000 element vector.

Comment: @Manetheran Yes that's why I didn't want to use `xrange` at the beginning! But anyway as it seems that the problem comes from my computer and is not generalized to `R` and `Python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Verdict:

The cause for this is the printing, In python writing to stdout is quite slow when comparing with `R` so trying to write to the stdout `10000` TIMES! in python might seem a bit slow (ignoring the range overhead) however printing it in one go reduces this gap significantly.

This code is much quicker because it writes to stdout only once:

```
lst = []

for i in range(10000):
    lst.append(i)

print lst
```

However this isn't because this writes to the stdout stream 10000 times:

```
for i in range(10000):
    print i
```

Also use the more memory efficient `xrange()` function and due to causes such as these only python 2's `range()` function has been replaced with the `xrange()` function in python 3...

It must be said that no matter what your original code only took about 5-6 seconds not 5 minutes...